# How to relink bitlocker and TPM? (veracrypt's encrypted disk)

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, disk-encryption, veracrypt

I don't know if this question has been asked already, but here it is:

Since I've encrypted my system disk on my tablet with veracrypt, bitlocker is asking it's recovery key each time on boot because (what the error message says in eventviewer) it can't contact the TPM device anymore. I previously had encrypted my disk with bitlocker. Is there a way to relink bitlocker and the TPM device (still according to the error message) or is it just the bitlocker way to say that another encrypting software have changed the data?

I need to say maybe that I'm not stuck, I have the recovery key recorded somewhere else and so I jsut need to type it in each time. It's just that it is not supposed to ask that at each boot.

In the perfect scenario I would like that veracrypt is still used and so asking me at boot the password and then bitlocker would be still in use but not asking me for the recovery key. I don't see or understand why bitlocker can't verify the TPM device anymore just because veracrypt did encrypt the disk afterwards?

yes I'm under windows 10 Pro
and there is no problem to use both togetehr. Bitlocker was encrypting the disk using the SSD encryption algorithm with the help of the TPM device and as planned, bitlocker wasn't asking for the recovery key because it was capable to use the TPM device for that at boot. Veracrypt have then be used to encrypt the disk in a software manner, it's very efficient using the AES algorithm, no problem of slowing down here. But then bitlocker was suddenly asking the recovery key after the veracrypt screen asking for the master password.

Comment: Why would you use two drive encryptions? If you already to full disk encryption with Veracrypt just deactivate BitLocker?

Comment: I was waiting for this question :) Well each of them has its strength and its disavantages. Bitlocker is not bad as its essence even if it has been breached by researchers, it would give enormous effort and knowledge to break the encryption and the encryption is effortless because of the harddrive capabilities and TPM presence, so it's done without any cpu effort or anything. totally fluid. 
On the other hand veracrypt is software based, even if it is very efficient with the AES algorithm it's cpu cost. But with veracrypt you have the option to have a password asked at boot(not BitLocker).

Comment: And there is no problem of having them both whatsoever and certainly not about corrupting files or anything, not in this case since bitLocker is not being made in a software capacity but as a hardware capacity which is totally different.

Comment: It's still nonsense but it's your choice. What did you do to active them both? Did you do BitLocker first and VeraCrypt afterwards? If you did, you modified your boot files and tampered with the system from a BitLocker perspective. In addition it is possible to use [BitLocker with pre-boot authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-countermeasures). You could check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/4470779/bitlocker-recovery-key-prompt-after-uefi-update-on-surface-book-2) but will have to adapt it.

Comment: I don't think it's nonsense but okey I can see your point of view but I think it's more a principle standpoint tahn an actual one. 
I first activate bitlocker then veracrypt. So if I deactivate bootlocker completely and then reactivate it, will it catch give it the right setup? 
I don't necessarely need the preboot auth for bitlocker since I have veracrypt but thanks for the tip

Comment: Yes, it would be worth a try to do it that way around. It might no necessarily be successful but you would know that BitLocker should see the "correct" information and/or you could check out the second link and see where that takes you.